# When should the function attribute noreturn be used in C?

Tags: c, function, void

I've recently found out about the `noreturn` attribute (I'm referring to C language, and not to C++ language; I'm working on a C project which uses a library where an equivalent is defined and it's destined only for C usage).

When is it considered good practice to use the `noreturn` attribute?
In all void function declarations? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: There is also the gcc `__attribute__((noreturn))`

Comment: `_Noreturn` does have the advantage of being standard, though, unlike GCC's extensions.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I didn't say otherwise. But the OP is almost certainly referring to the gcc attribute.

Answer (score 10):

Don't do that for your `void` functions, this would have undefined behavior.

The new C11 construct `_Noreturn` should only be used when you know that your function will never return to the caller. This can e.g be the case when it *unconditionally* makes a call to `abort`, `exit` or alike, or when you enter an infinite loop.

The purpose of that is that the compiler can optimize the call on the *calling* side, in particular by cutting off the whole branch of execution that comes after the call.

Generally `void` functions are *not* of that kind, they return to the caller, just that on that return they don't provide a value that will be used. For most such functions declaring them is *fundamentally wrong*.

The C11 syntax is `_Noreturn` or with a macro `noreturn`. Not all compilers do yet implement that feature, but most have extensions to C99 (or C89) that provides the same feature. On that platforms you can usually define a macro `noreturn` that would be an upward compatible replacement.

Comment: That said, situations where you should use `_Noreturn` in a real life app should be extremely rare. The only valid case is probably really wrappers for `abort` and `exit`, because even an "infinite" loop should usually have a `break` in it. And, as the gcc people acknowledge, the optimization potential is very slight - each `_Noreturn` function can only be called once, after all (if it's not recursive, that is). So, the only real use case is to quench warnings about uninitialized variables.

Comment: @cmaster, I agree that it is probably rare and that dead code elimination is in most cases a minor optimization objective. But why a `_Noreturn` function wouldn't be recursive, I don't see. This is probably rare to non existent, but shouldn't be excluded as such.

Comment: I didn't mean to say that it cannot be recursive. Of course it can be, which I tried to acknowledge with "(if it's not recursive, that is)". Probably, I should have made my meaning a bit clearer. As a matter of fact, there is nothing to stop you from calling, recursively or not, a `_Noreturn` function any number of times, using cheats like `longjmp()`. But any sane program won't do this, and that's why it's of no concern for optimization.

Answer (score 6):

I've used them for a main(...) function that had an infinite while loop.  It was for an embedded system.

The noreturn attribute pacified a compiler warning.

To answer your question, I would use it when a function never returns (i.e. infinite while loop) and your compiler is emitting a warning.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean [`__declspec(noreturn)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ktzx3s.aspx) or [`__attribute__ ((noreturn));`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2//gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bnoreturn_007d-function-attribute-2160).

It's a good idea to tell your compiler when a function does not return, that it does not, so it can do some optimizations, or actually avoid some kind of optimizations.

[`_NoReturn`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v121v141/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlc121.aix.doc%2Flanguage_ref%2Fnoreturn.html) is standard [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)).

Comment: The point is more quenching unfounded warnings about use of uninitialized variables than optimization.